# How to remove unwanted characters from String (using Java8 collection APIs)

Tags: json, collections, java-8

I am doing some collection/java8 processing that is giving me some trouble. I have an input string similar to the following:

```
String  test = "{\"module\":\"taping\",\"id\":\"abc123\"}";
```

I am using the following String-to-Map conversion to help with building the subsequent json.

```
Map<String, String> reconstructedUtilMap = Arrays.stream(test.split(","))
                .map(s -> s.split(":", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

The problem I am having is that the result (as follows):

```
\"id\" -> \"abc123\"}
{\"module\" -> \"taping\"
```

still has the curly braces and the escaped double quotes.I need to have the opening and closing curly braces removed, as well as the escaped quotes, because when I covert to json (the final goal), it leaving the braces and the escaped quotes:

```
 JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
 JsonObject fieldObj = new JsonObject();

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : reconstructedUtilMap.entrySet()) {
            fieldObj.add(entry.getKey(), jsonSerializationContext.serialize(entry.getValue()));
        }
json.add("result",  fieldObj);
```

and the json result being:

```
"result": {
      "\"id\"": "\"abc123\"}",
      "{\"module\"": "\"screening\""
    }
```

I need it to be:

```
"result": {
      "id": "abc12"",
      "module": "screening"
    }
```

I want to keep in the mindset of using java8 to remove the unwanted characters. Grateful for ideas. thanks!

Comment: Since the input appears to be JSON, you should by parsing it using a JSON parser.  But if you simply want to embed the JSON object inside another one, as implied by the examples, then you could do that without any massaging; e.g. `String output = "{\"result\": " + test + "}";`

Comment: I really am not understanding how that is an answer. thanks though.

Comment: Well you said: *"Grateful for ideas"*.  My idea is that you should be doing this another way.  This looks like an X-Y problem to me. Perhaps you should explained clearly what you are trying to achieve.  Are you simply trying to embed the `test` fragment in a larger JSON result?

Comment: sorry, I have to get from: "{\"module\":\"taping\",\"id\":\"abc123\"}" , to : "result": {
      "id": "abc12"",
      "module": "screening"
    } . That is exactly what i need. I am open to alternatives to the path i started on.

Comment: Map<String, String> reconstructedUtilMap = Arrays.stream(test.split(","))
                .map(s -> s.split(":", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0].replaceAll("\\\"", ""), s -> s[1].replaceAll("\\\"", "")))

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this, depending on what you are actually doing here.

### Solution #1

If you are simply reconstructing the original JSON embedded in a larger JSON object, then this should work:

```
String test = "{\"module\":\"taping\",\"id\":\"abc123\"}";

String result = "{\"result\": " + test + "}";
```

If this is all you are doing you don't need to massage the `test` JSON ... assuming that it is valid JSON ... which it is in your example.

### Solution #2

If you need to modify the JSON in the `test` string, then this is the simple way to do it.

```
JSONObject testJSON = new JSONObject(test);

// Make your changes to testJSON via the JSONObject API

JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
result.add("result", testJSON);
```

Using the Java EE `JsonObject` API, that would be:

```
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(test));
JsonObject testJSON = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close();

JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
result.add("result", testJSON);
return result;
```

Using the GSON `JsonObject`:

```
JsonElement testJSON = new JsonParser().parse(test);

JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
result.add("result", testJSON);
return result;     // a JsonElement.
```

---

Dealing with embedded escapes and double quotes using string bashing or regexes is complicated and messy and error prone<sup>1</sup> ... and (IMO) negates any (possible) advantages of using Java 8+ streams.

Note, your example seems to imply that you want the JSON object's fields in a specific order.  Be aware that the JSON specs all state that JSON object fields are not ordered.  A JSON parser is liable to ignore any (incorrectly) implied ordering in the serialization.

If your application depends on the implied ordering then you are doing it incorrectly.  *Some* JSON APIs have ways to serialize in a specific order and preserve the order when serializing.  But a better approach would be to redesign your JSON schema to use an JSON array for the ordered sequence of name / value pairs.

---

<sup>1 - For example, your existing approach of splitting using `:` or `,` will fail if the attribute name or value strings in the `test` JSON *could* contain those characters.  Addressing just this flaw would be messy, and it would be worse if the values could be nested JSON objects or arrays.</sup>

Comment: Stephen. Thanks for your thoughtful, careful response. I should have mentioned, my solution ultimately must return JsonElement, and cannot throw or catch any new exceptions due to existing code issues. That negates: JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(test));
JsonObject testJSON = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close(); or other similar.

Comment: I don't understand what you just wrote (you try reading it!) ... but if it answers the question that you asked, you should write it up properly as an answer.

Comment: It does not answer the question no. I think I will delete my post as it is clearly not going to be helpful to anyone. Only you have responded, you have been frustrated with it, and it has not been answered successfully.

Comment: I think I have figured out which JSON API you are using now ...

Comment: And I think I have answered the question in a way that will be helpful for others ... if not for you.  So please don't delete the question and cause my work to be discarded.

Comment: ok I won't delete it.